# WebService Registrando dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    DM_Principal.pLarWS := CreateComObject(LarWS_TLB.CLASS_WS) as IWS;
  except
    WinExec( 'regasm LarWS.dll /tlb:LarWS.tlb',SW_HIDE);
    Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    Sleep(3000);
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    DM_Principal.pLarWS := CreateComObject(LarWS_TLB.CLASS_WS) as IWS;
  end;

DM_Principal:
  private
    larWS: IWS;
  public
    property pLarWS: IWS read larWS write larWS;
```

Ao executar sem internet o sistema entra em loop na rotina:

```
DM_Principal.pLarWS := CreateComObject(LarWS_TLB.CLASS_WS) as IWS;
```

Não conseguindo registrar, se eu tentar mudar o código para registrar no REGASM também entrar em loop infinito.

Segue o link do arquivo LARWS_TLB.pas
[Arquivo.](https://pastebin.com/iK7LiiRK)

Comment: Mas como você configurou a conexão com o banco de dados? ele está na mesma máquina?

Comment: Sim esta na mesma máquina. Mas o banco interfere em alguma coisa?

Comment: Me parece algum erro de permissão, algum recurso que a credencial utilizada não tem privilégio ou algum caminho que não consegue acessar. Sem falar na descrição do erro em si.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo mas quando executo com internet/webservice funciona, o problema está quando não tiver internet ou o WebService estiver offline.

Comment: O que é essa `LarWS.dll` onde podemos encontrar isto para simular o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função CreateComObject(GUID: TGUID) cria uma nova instância de um objeto COM. Antes criar a instância, ela precisa fazer o seguinte:

- Carregar a .dll que contém a classe que implementa a interface identificada por essa GUID (vou chamar de classeGuid). Nesse caso a LarWS.dll.
- Criar uma instância da classe fábrica da classeGuid (classe responsável por fabricar objetos da classeGuid).
- Solicitar a fábrica para criar uma nova instância da classeGuid.

Durante esse processo, um bocado de código da LarWS.dll é executado. Se esse código estiver tentando acessar algo na internet ou na rede local, quando não tiver internet/rede ele vai ficar executando até atingir o tempo limite de resposta (timeout). Dando a impressão que o programa travou.

Se você tem o código dessa LarWS.dll, você precisa abri-lo e ver se há algum tipo de conexão sendo aberta, durante a inicialização da dll, da classe fábrica ou no construtor da classeGuid.